# $\mathbb{Z}$ action on the unit circle $S^1$

Tags: group-actions, topological-groups

Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number and consider the $\mathbb{Z}$ action on the unit circle $S^1$ given by $e^{2\pi ix}.n=e^{2\pi i(x+n\alpha)}, n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Can we get an example of a subspace of $S^1$ that is invariant under the restricted action by $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: The empty set $\varnothing$, the whole space $S^1$ and any set $\{\mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm i(x+n\alpha)}\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ for fixed $x$ are examples of $\mathbb N$-invariant subspaces. Are you looking for anything less trivial? What's the motivation of this question?

Comment: I am in the middle of doing with the action by $\mathbb{Z}$. I  need a subspace $D$ of $S^1$ such that $D$ is $\mathbb{N}$ invariant and $\cup_{a \in \mathbb{N}} D-a=S^1$

Comment: What's $D-a$? Please add context and details to your question body by [editing](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4177060/edit) it.

Comment: There are no other restrictions? Then $D = S^1$ works.